# Stretch the surface along the entire height which is in row

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have a lazy column in which there is a list of cards in which there is a row and two columns in it, the height of the first column is much larger than the second. The second column has text with a different background made using a surface. The fillMaxHeight modifiers do not work. Already tried to do it by other means:
1)

```
Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
```

However, there is a problem, this only works with static components, and this is a lazy line in my columns, and the composition starts to crash
2) Get the height in this way.

```
//Save height
 val heightIs = remember {
            mutableStateOf(0.dp)
        }
//Get the context
val localDensity = LocalDensity.current

Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f).onSizeChanged{cord->
                    heightIs.value = with(localDensity){
                         cord.height.toDp()
                    }
```

The problem with this solution is that when there is no lazy row, it doesn't properly distribute the height.

Short code:

```
 Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 2.dp, vertical = 4.dp), elevation = 4.dp
        ) {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
                Column(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(0.7f)) {
                    Surface(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    ) {
                        Row(
                            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = historyOrderItem.id.toString(),
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = historyOrderItem.status,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    LazyRow(modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                        items(items = historyOrderItem.items, key = { it.itemId }) {
                            ItemDoneOrderShort(it)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                    Row(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
                    ) {
                        TextButton(onClick = { onCopy(historyOrderItem) }) {
                            Text(
                                text = "ПОВТОРИТЬ",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.h6,
                                textAlign = TextAlign.Right,
                                maxLines = 1,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.colorAccent) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Оплатить",
                            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h5,
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the 2 columns with the same height?

Comment: Yes, the second column with a different color, for some reason does not fill all the available space.

Comment: Post a reproducible example

Comment: I have added the code. This code crashes.

Comment: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc. To mitigate this:
    - if intrinsic measurements are used to achieve 'match parent' sizing,, consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured, making intrinsic measurement not needed
    - adding a size modifier to the component, in order to fast return the queried intrinsic measurement.